# Can i also use #{} interpolation to insert complicated expressions in a HTML-style attribute use jade template for nodejs

Tags: pug

How I can use `#{}` interpolation to insert complicated expressions in a HTML-style attribute?

```
span(class="widget_#{widget.number}")
```

Comment: Yo! Unless you're unhappy with @Michi's solution, could you accept it as the answer, please.

Answer (score 5):

You can use it the Javascript way.

```
span(class="widget_" + widget.number)
```

Comment: @Michi thank you very much for the answer! Really helped me!